# Shortcut for "Find Result 1" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Shortcut for "Find Result 1" in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no predefined shortcut for that (at least in VS 2005) but just select `Customize...` from the `Options` menu, press the `Keyboard...` button and then create a suitable shortcut for `View.FindResults1`.

Answer (score 14):

**Hotkeys for Visual Studio 2010 - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>**

**Hotkeys for Visual Studio 2015 - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>**

**Hotkeys for Visual Studio 2017 - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>**

**Hotkeys for Visual Studio 2022 - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>(make selection with arrows) + <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

If you don't feel like customizing your own shortcuts, or you use different environments where you can't always rely on your customization being present, you can always go the old school route of just navigating the menus via hotkeys.

For instance, in Visual Studio 2010, you can just type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

- Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> opens up the "View" menu.
- Typing <kbd>n</kbd> opens up the "Find Results" menu item in the View menu.
- Typing <kbd>1</kbd> selects the "Find Results 1" menu item, thereby opening and setting focus to the "Find Results 1" window.
- Likewise, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> opens up the "Find Results 2" window.

If you do this enough, it's like any other keyboard shortcut, and becomes second nature.

**ProTip**

You can discover the hotkey shortcut to any menu item you need by just hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and looking at the letters that are underlined in the menus. This applies to pretty much any windows program you will ever use.

Comment: It is `Alt + v, n, n, →, 2` in VS2015

Comment: @user3009578 Thanks - I've updated the answer for VS2015.

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio Professional 2013 (not sure about the other version) the function key "F8" will take you to the next result in the Find Results window, and "Shift-F8" will take you in the reverse direction (i.e. find previous result).

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for! Works in VS2017 as well

Answer (score 1):

You can assign keyboard shortcuts as you please through Tools > Customize > keyboard.

In the `show commands containing` textbox type `View.FindResults1`.

In the `Press shortcut keys` textbox type in the shortcuts you want to add and then press the **Assign** button.